Spectral sequence of $\text { the fibration } E X \xrightarrow{\Omega X} X$
I'm studying Fomenko-Fuchs Lecture 22.3 and i'm stuck on the proof of the following theorem at page 333:

Theorem: Let X be a topological space (with a base point), and let the space $X$ be $(n-1)$-connected, that is,
$$
\pi_0(X)=\pi_1(X)=\ldots=\pi_{n-1}(X)=0 .
$$
Then
$$
H_r(X) \cong H_{r-1}(\Omega X) \text { for } r \leq 2 n-2 \text {, }
$$

This is the graph they use of $E^2_{p,q}$ of the spectral sequence of $\text { the fibration } E X \xrightarrow{\Omega X} X$

By the end of the proof they say:

The corner cell contains the group $E_{n, n-1}^2$. The only potentially nonzero differential from this cell is directed to the $(2 n-2)$ nd cell of the zeroth column; the only differential directed to this cell comes from the $2 n$th cell in the zeroth row. Thus, the groups below the $(2 n-2)$ nd cell in the zeroth column and the groups to the left of the $2 n$th cell of the zeroth row can be annihilated only by differentials acting from the zeroth row to the zeroth column (and they must be annihilated since the $E^{\infty}$ term is zero). This shows that (actually, for all $r$ ) the differential $d_{r, 0}^r: E_{r, 0}^r \rightarrow E_{0, r-1}^r$ must be an isomorphism

I understand that the only potentially nonzero differential from the corner cell is directed to the $(2 n-2)$nd cell of the zeroth column and the only differential directed to the corner cell comes from the $2 n$th cell in the zeroth row, but I don't understand why it follows that the differential $d_{r, 0}^r$ is an isomorphism.
Why is it true that the only differential that annihilates the groups to the left of the $2 n$th cell of the zeroth row is the differential acting from the zeroth row to the zeroth column? Every other differential should annihilate the $2 n$th cell of the zeroth row, since the codomains are $0$.
What do they mean when they say that they must be annihilated since the $E^{\infty}$ term is zero?

Since $EX$ is contractible, $E^\infty_{p, q}$ must be 0 for all $(p, q) \neq 0$; this is what is meant by "the $E^\infty$-term is zero." In particular, this means that for each $(p, q) \neq (0, 0)$ there is some $r \geq 2$ such that $E^r_{p, q} = 0$.
What does this mean for the groups $E^2_{0, q}$ and $E^2_{p, 0}$ for small $p, q$ (assuming $n \gg 0$ for simplicity's sake)? Looking at $E^2_{p, 0}$, there's a differential $d^2\colon E^2_{p, 0} \to E^2_{p - 2, 1}$ whose codomain is 0. The kernel (!) of this map is what makes it onto the $E^3$-page, so $E^3_{p, 0} \cong E^2_{p, 0}$. Same for the "outgoing" $d^3$, $d^4$, etc., until you get to $d^p\colon E^p_{p, 0} \cong E^2_{p, 0} \to E^p_{0, p - 1}$. If this differential were 0, then we would have $E^{p + 1}_{p, 0} \cong E^p_{p, 0}$, but this is bad, because all further outgoing differentials at that index have codomain left of the $q$-axis and must therefore be 0, oops! So in fact this $d^p$ is not just non-zero, but it can't have nontrivial kernel since that would give a nontrivial $E^{p + 1}$-term.
Dually, we have that for the groups $E^2_{0, q}$ the cokernels of the incoming differentials are what makes it over onto the next page, so we similarly conclude that the only incoming differential that's possibly nontrivial, namely the one originating in zeroth row, must be surjective.
Together this shows that the differentials from the bottom row to the leftmost column must be isomorphisms in the appropriate range.
